# convert array from mysql to array in array PHP

Tags: php

Hello i have a problem with convert array from mysql to be identical with this example generate:

```
                    'groups' => [
                        (first column)9480 => [423](next column), //1
                        42774 => [400], //2
                    ],
```

I have a two column in mysql First and Next and my question is how i can generate to up example with my two column in mysql

i tried:

```
$listagildi = $reg->sql->query('select `channelid`,`group` From special_channels');
$testg = $listagildi->fetchAll();
$arr = array('groups' => [$testg], );
```

Comment: An array in MySQL? MySQL does not have a data type of array. Are you serializing the data somehow?

Comment: Are you serializing the data somehow? No

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please share your schema, some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Do you want an array of key-value pairs where the value of the first column is the key and the value of the second column is the value? And each row from the database is a key-value pair?